# Does it make use async in this case? I'm trying to understand event loop + promise

Tags: javascript, multithreading, promise, event-loop

I made up an example here to to try to understand better how single thread + event loop + Promise work.

```
function add(a, b) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(a + b);
  });
}

add(3, 6).then(v => console.log(v));
console.log('test 1');
```

In this case the only thing that I'm doing here is sending **add** to the end of the event loop queue or it will be processed in a different thread?

If it is the case that I'm just sending to the end, so I can assume that using Promise without a http call or any other web api thing is useless, right?

Edit: I removed async as pointed out by @twharmon

Comment: A promise is just a design pattern. You can write a promise class yourself - it has no need for low-level changes in the language (though at least on node.js promises are implemented in C for performance). Indeed, before promises became standard and integrated into the language itself several promise libraries appeared that implemented several styles of promises - jQuery's deferred, bluebird, Q etc. And indeed some libraries like Q and bluebird is similar enough to modern Promise that they can be mixed together - you can start with a Q promise then chain it with a Promise

Comment: .. if you feel like taking on a challenge you can try implementing the Promise class yourself. I did that several years ago when I wanted to understand how promises work

Comment: A promise does not necessarily need to add anything to the event loop or start a new thread. All a promise does is call the function you pass to `.then()` when `resolve()` is called. It is purely an OO design pattern. It does not create anything asynchronous. It is a design pattern that can make handling asynchronous functions easier to read

Comment: The best way to play around with promises to understand how it works is to start a node.js interactive shell

Comment: Type: node, then once node starts type: `foo; new Promise((resolve, reject) => foo = resolve).then(x => console.log('resolve is called', x))`

Comment: Now you have a promise and you have assigned `resolve` to the variable `foo`. Next type `foo('hello world')` and you will see `resolve is called hello world`

Comment: None of the steps above require the event loop or any threads. `.then()` will simply execute its callback when `resolve()` is called, in this case when `foo()` is called

Comment: Thanks a lot @slebetman. But so imagine that I have a function that does a heavy processing. Making it return a Promise will not help at all right? Because In the end of the day it will be processed by the "main" thread, right?

Comment: Yes. If you need multiple threads you need web workers in browsers or worker threads in node.js.

Answer (score 2):

> The only thing that I'm doing here is sending add to the end of the event loop queue or it will be processed in a different thread?

Yes, it will not do any multithreaded processing.

But no, it doesn't send `add` to the end of the event loop. It does defer the `v => console.log(v)` callback, but `add(3, 6)` is still called synchronously. And it doesn't even send the callback to the end of the event loop, like after already-fired timeouts, filesystem and network events, but only to the end of the microtask queue, which runs pretty much immediately before the next turn of the event loop.

> I can assume that using Promise without [doing something actually asynchronous] is useless

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I'll try to explain according to my understanding, I am up for a discussion & if am wrong, correct me please :)

So there's only `1` thread in javascript. And lets just talk about synchronous code. Javascript will start from first line of the code and start execution of all sync code, like `console.log()`, `airthmetic operations` etc.

If it faces any async code, like a `setTimeout` or a `promise`, it'll defer that code until no other piece of code is running.

For example, when you call `add(1,2).then(fn)`, a promise is created and the callback `fn` from `.then(fn)` is registered by the runtime engine. The runtime engine will move to the next line after `add()` and start execution of any synchronous code. Once all the synchronous code is executed, the callback of `fn` will be called if the promise `add()` is resolved.

Take the following example:

```
function add(a, b) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(a + b);
    });
}

add(3, 6).then(v => {
    throw new Error
});

while(1) {
    console.log("")
}
```

After `add()` is called, the js engine moves to a synchronous `while` loop. Now this is an infinite while loop which means the queue will never get empty for the callback of `add()` promise to execute. If it was a multithreaded environment, the callback of  `add()` would have executed in a second thread, throwing and Error and halting the program which never happens because of the single thread.

Now take a look at the second example:

```
function add(a, b) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            throw new Error
        }, 1000)
    });
}

add(3, 6).then(v => {
    console.log(v)
});

while(1) {
    console.log("")
}
```

Executing the above code, we see that throw new Error is never called because our program is again stuck at the infinite while loop. It means, the code inside the promise is not being executed (the `setTimeout` function) because if it was being any second thread, the `throw new Error` line would have been called halting the program.
What the js engine did was create a promise when `add()` was called, deferred the code of the promise, moved on to the next line of synchronous code. The code inside the promise will be called once the queue clears up, which in our example never will because of the infinite while loop.

I hope I made sense.

Comment: "*the code inside the promise is not being executed*" - you could be more precise with that. Does it refer to the code inside the `new Promise` callback, the code inside the `setTimeout` callback, or the code inside the `then` callback?

Comment: I don't see much of a difference in behaviour between the two examples, are they both necessary for the explanation? But yes, you do make sense.

Comment: There is a difference between the 2 examples, in first example `resolve(a + b);` is called before our code reaches the `while` loop i.e the promise is resolved when we reach the loop.
In second case, the `setTimeout` callback is deferred and we reach the while loop before the promise is resolved or the setTimeout callback is executed.

Comment: It does make sense! Thanks!